# php modifiers & cache concept

Tags: php, caching, browser-cache

Does Php have any modifiers like 'persistent' in java?

My purpose is to store Result sets which are retrieved from Database onto server RAM. When user next time searches for same values, I will not go to Database for retrieval again. Simply, I want to simulate cache on RAM.

I have no clue. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Not really.

You could either cache the results to a file, then load it, or use something like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) in front of your database to get this behaviour.

Alternatively, you could store data in $_SESSION, but that would of course be per user rather than globally.

Comment: but i don't want it in a file. Cant we assign this to a temp variable  and make it stay on RAM? Can we make any variable stay on RAM like this?

Comment: No. PHP doesn't work like that, each script is run from top to bottom, then exits. There isn't any persistance by design. You can use something like memcached to do this though in front of your DB rather than in your language.